How to use <unk> default token in input sentence in Transformer (OpenNMT) model
I'm using the OpenNMT library to develop a translation model.
I want to display certain tokens in their original language without translating them, or translate certain tokens to certain tokens only.
If you have any good ideas, please recommend them.
I've been trying to use custom tokens or  tokens to prevent them from being translated during translation, but I'm having trouble with this.
And modifying certain tokens before the attention operation has a negative impact on the attention operation, and I'm trying to figure out how to fix this.

What i want
ex) I like apples for breakfast. -> 나는 아침에 먹는 apples를 좋아합니다.
ex) I like unk for breackfast. -> 나는 아침에 먹는 unk를 좋아합니다.
or
ex) I like apples for breakfast. -> 나는 아침에 먹는 사과를 좋아합니다.
I want find that position of "apples"  = position of "사과"
